# Is there a way to execte jquery event after ajax callback has been completed?

Tags: 8, javascript, ajax

Having a simple form with few input fields. 
After clicking on ajax callback submit button, I'm returning the table element.

### Code:

```
//Hypertension treatment
        $form['hyper_treat'] = array (
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => ('Hypertension treatment:'),                                  
      '#options' => array(
        'y' => 'Yes', 
        'n' => 'No'
      ),
    );


//Hypercholesterolemia
    $form['hyperchol'] = array (
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => ('Hypercholesterolemia:'),                                        
  '#options' => array(
    'y' => 'Yes', 
    'n' => 'No'
  ),
);

//submit button
    $form['action'] = [
    '#prefix' => '<div id = "ajax_submit">',
     '#name' => 'ajax_action',
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::setMessage',
    'wrapper' => 'scrollable',
    'method' => 'replaceWith',
    'effect' => 'fade', 
    ],
    ];

    //table
    $form['table'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="scrollable" class = "col-md-8"><h4>View Data</h4>',
        '#type' => 'tableselect',
         '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#header' => $header,
         '#options' => $options,
        '#disabled' => $disabled,
        '#attributes' => array('id' => 'sort-table'),
        '#empty' => t('Select criteria and search data'),
      );

//callback function
   public function setMessage(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $options = getOptions(); //gets the associative array
  $form['table']['#options'] = $options;
  return $form['table'];
}
```

I had issues with the pagination and sorting of the table returned using ajax. 
So I thought of using "Datatables" as the alternative option.

So after the callback, I would want to apply the below jquery to have the table shown as a datatable.

```
 $('#sort-table').DataTable( {
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
```

Tried executing the 'mousedown' event for the button but the jquery executes before the ajax callback.

Is there a possible way to represent the $form['table'] element returned from the ajax callback, as a datatable?

[image]

Triggering any other event after table returned would display it as a datatable, but I'm looking to have the returned table displayed as a datatable immediately after the $form['table'] is returned. This happens only when the jquery snippet is executed immediately after the table element is returned from the ajax callback function.

Comment: Normally you put the js code in a `Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior` object and attach it as library. On each ajax request the Drupal behaviors are run again, with the context limited to the newly loaded content.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing and it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom ajax commands for this. Ajax commands are php classes that correspond to a JS function on the server, which the Drupal JS API calls after Ajax responses.

At a quick lookover, [this tutorial](https://www.mike-miles.com/blog/creating-ajax-callback-commands-drupal-8) looks like it gives a good overview on how to create a custom Ajax command in Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) and [`ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) methods among [other ajax event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/). So on the client side you could try something like this:

```
jQuery.ajaxSuccess(function(){
    $('#sort-table').DataTable( {
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    });
});
```

Comment: Sure, but just be careful you are invoking it against the exact thing you want to touch. Otherwise, this will fire every single time any AJAX has completed in the application. I wrote some conditions around this before... let me see if I can find them.

Comment: Right here - you will want to check for the triggering element. This was the only way I could tell _what_ triggered AJAX, so I knew if I wanted to continue and fire specific code: http://kevinquillen.com/javascript/2014/06/04/kill-the-ajax-throbber

Comment: putting the js code within Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior object solved the problem.